# A git diff which shows the differences between shared files, and ignores unshared files

Tags: git

I want to see the differences between all files that exist in both commitA and commitB.  If a file exists in one commit but not in the other, it should be ignored.  Is there an easy command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--diff-filter` to restrict the diff to modified files only:

```
git diff --diff-filter=M commitA commitB
```